# How do I disable the Lenovo on-screen keybard?

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, on-screen-keyboard

For a while now I have been receiving an on-screen keyboard symbol on a Lenovo Yoga with Windows 10. When I press on it, an on-screen keyboard appears. This is getting on my nerves as I accidentally click on it a few times per day.

Is there any way I can disable it? I haven't found any process that I can kill or any open program in the task manager. It is not the Windows on-screen keyboard.

Here are the screenshots:

1. keyboard symbol

[image: Symbol in all text fields]

2. Actual on-screen keyboard
   [image: Actual keyboard]